# VueJs webapplication interactive parts do not work properly on some browsers/systems

Tags: browser, vuejs2, styling

I'm a pretty jr developer, so I hope the solution to my issue is much more simple then what what is feels like right now.

It concerns a web application build with VueJS. There seems to be styling issues within browsers on some machines. At the moment it "looks" like that the application running on the same operating system using the same browser version still produces different results. On my own machine and on many others the application worked perfectly on Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Safari. Could anyone point me into the right direction of what this could be? Browser settings, something I need to add when building my VueJS app? See below for examples of how it should and should not look.

How it should look:

[image: How it should look]

How it should not look:

[image: How it should not look]

Sometimes a click also does not lead to turning off the coloring or turn it back on. Please see a code example for the button generation below:

```
    <div class="category-colony-container">
          <div class="category-colonies-row-container" v-for="colony in lotStateColonies" :key="colony.id">
            <button class="colony-button" v-bind:id="colony.id" :style="getColonyCheckedStatus(colony.id) ? {'background-color' : colony.color.concat(getColonyOpacity)} : {'background-color' : 'transparent'} " @click="toggleColonyVisibility">{{colony.description}}</button>
          </div>
```